# According to Catholic doctrine, why did Jesus Christ have to die to save mankind if only the physical body is involved in death?

Tags: catholicism, death, souls, immortality, redemption

Catholics say:The soul is immortal; all humans have one. Adam sinned and his physical body returned to  dust, but his soul moved on to phase 2.

According to Catholic doctrine, why does the whole plan of redemption depend on the physical death of Jesus Christs human body?  How are we saved from Adamic death which according to doctrine was death of physical body only?

Comment: Simple. More than the physical body is involved. A relationship with God ruined by sin is a stake.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I recommend checking out the following posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": the [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?,](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer) This site values questions and answers that are objectively verifiable. Opinion answers are discouraged.

Comment: I've edited to clarify the question, which I happen to think is a good one. If the edited version is not exactly what you wanted to ask, please do re-edit it.

Comment: This question confuses and equates *cessation to exist* with *cessation to live*.

Comment: Can you back up the claim that according to Catholic doctrine the Adamic death was only physical?

Comment: There are plenty of passages in the Bible that give clear answers to this question.  The answer does not need to be subjective opinion, but rather Christian orthodox doctrine based on Scripture and backed by accepted Catholic and protestant theologians.  This is a goood question that should be taken off hold.

Comment: @curuousdanni Catholic doctrine of immortality of the soul leaves me believing only physical Adam died

Comment: The question does not have an answer from a Catholic perspective.

Comment: Death involves both the body and the soul, because it is the separation of the two that constitutes death.  As a result of the separation, the body, being a material entity, decays, whereas the soul, being a spiritual entity, does not decay. Nevertheless, the soul is not a complete person as long as it is deprived of the body. This is one reason why there will be a resurrection, when our souls and bodies are reunited and we become complete, living people again.

Answer (score 1):

### What is death according to Catholicism?

> Death consists in the separation of soul and body. - Cf. Individual
>   eschatology, [Eschatology | New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/05528b.htm).

### Can the body live after it is separated from the soul?

The LORD teaches that it is [the spirit that gives life, the flesh is of no avail](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%206%3A63&version=RSVCE). Therefore with death, while the soul goes on, the body returns to dust from which it was taken because of itself it contributes nothing to the living person.

Cf. Also [Eccl 12:7 (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ecclesiastes%2012%3A7&version=RSVCE): *and the dust returns to the earth as it was, and the spirit returns to God who gave it*.

### What other scriptural passages may assist the OP in the proper understanding of Catholic teaching regarding death?

- [So they and all that belonged to them went down alive into Sheol [the abode of the dead]; and the earth closed over them, and they perished from the midst of the assembly](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers%2016%3A33&version=RSVCE).
- [cut off out of the land of the living](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=cut%20off%20the%20land%20of%20the%20living&qs_version=RSVCE).

Therefore they are dead those who are taken out of the land of the living to go down to sheol, the abode of the dead.

Another expression is *"putting off one's tent"* as in [2 Pt 1:14 (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Peter%201%3A14&version=RSVCE).

Cf. Also [Phil 1:21-23 (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Philippians%201%3A21-23&version=RSVCE), where St. Paul speaks of what he gains via death, i.e., going to be with Christ.

Therefore the OP's question:

> According to Catholic doctrine, why does the whole plan of redemption
>   depend on the physical death of Jesus Christs (sic) human body? How
>   are we saved from Adamic death which according to doctrine was death
>   of physical body only?

cannot be answered from a Catholic perspective because it seems death is understood as the *"death of [the] physical body only"*, while the Catholic definition and understanding of death in line with scripture is that **death consists in the separation of soul and body**.

---

---

Cf. This [answer of mine](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/46236/how-is-the-matter-of-why-the-son-of-god-needed-to-be-sacrificed-explained-in-the/46270#46270) to: [How is the matter of why the Son of God needed to be sacrificed explained in the Roman Catholic Church? | C.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/46236/how-is-the-matter-of-why-the-son-of-god-needed-to-be-sacrificed-explained-in-the).

Comment: clarify why op is wrong in saying only Adams body died   clarify why an immortal soul needs saving from death

Comment: @Pam 1) Jesus saves from sin [cf. Mt 1:21] and the consequences from sin e.g death [cf. Rm 6:22-23] and the last enemy to be destroyed is death [cf. 1 Cor 15:26]. 2) Other questions to consider from human experience: without salvation, what good does a disembodied soul do here on earth, i.e., in the land of the living? It can't protect the widow or the orphan, provide companionship, etc. Salvation [will] rights those ills. 3) What good does the soul in mortal sin experience even if it goes on? According to Catholicism, it goes to hell which is the second death. Salvation saves from hell.

Comment: @Pam In my answer  *the spirit that gives life, the flesh is of no avail* so clearly *Can the body live after it is separated from the body?* cannot be a question I would ask.

Comment: @Pam Go ahead and edit and perhaps I could then understand what you are trying to convey and and with that understanding, let the edit stand. By others edits, the intent of a question is known or an answer made more correct and thus contributing to making the site better.